# Running a .Net Standard 2.0 Application on a PC with .Net Framework 4.6.2

Tags: c#, .net

I added a new project to an existing solution. All of the other projects are compiled to .Net Framework 4.6.2. The new project is .Net Standard 2.0. When this is deployed to a client machine (it's a windows application) will it run if the machine only has .Net Framework 4.6.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the documentation it will.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Doc says the minimum version required is 4.6.1

Comment: This answer should be correct in 99.9% cases, while in edge cases there can be `PlatformNotSupportedException`, as 4.7.1 is the very first release to fully support .NET Standard 2.0 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/17/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-1/